# Update array filtering by 2 fields

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

I don't know if it is possible.

I'm trying to do an automatic process to update all elements of a nested array in some documents. The array hasn't a fixed length.

Below is a simplified example of the collection:

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5ba2e413a4dd01725a658c63"),
    "MyOwnID" : "123456789",
    "MyArray" : [ 
        {
            Field1: 'FooName1',
            Field2: 'FooSpec1',
            FieldToUpdate: '...'
        },
        {
            Field1: 'FooName1',
            Field2: 'FooSpec2',
            FieldToUpdate: '...'
        },
        {
         ... More elements ...
        }
    ]
},
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5ba2e413a4dd01725a658c63"),
    "MyOwnID" : "987654321",
    "MyArray" : [ 
        {
            Field1: 'FooName1',
            Field2: 'FooSpec1',
            FieldToUpdate: '...'
        },
        {
            Field1: 'FooName2',
            Field2: 'FooSpec2',
            FieldToUpdate: '...'
        },

    ]
}
```

I tried and it worked for the first element:

Query for the second element:

```
db.getCollection('works').findOneAndUpdate(
    { MyOwnID: '123456789', '$and':[ { 'MyArray.Field1': 'FooName1' },{ 'MyArray.Field2': 'FooSpec1' } ] } , 
    { '$set': { 'MyArray.$.FieldToUpdate': 1234} } 
)
```

But when I try to update the second element only the first is updated.

Query for the second element:

```
db.getCollection('works').findOneAndUpdate(
        { MyOwnID: '123456789', '$and':[ { 'MyArray.Field1': 'FooName1' },{ 'MyArray.Field2': 'FooSpec2' } ] } , 
        { '$set': { 'MyArray.$.FieldToUpdate': 4321} } 
    )
```

I tried with arrayFilters option and $elemMatch, both give me an error.

Any options?

Comment: You have both elements with the same _id and then you have both of your `MyOwnID` matching `123456789`. Aren't you trying to update `123456789` and then `987654321`?

Comment: Yes first i want to update the elements in the array for document 123456789 and then the elements in the array for documente 987654321. It is just an example, the real document is larger than the example.

Comment: But in your example you are updating `123456789` twice. 2nd `findOneAndUpdate` should be with `MyOwnID: '987654321'`

Comment: yes, the problem is not update the document itself, is update the elements in the array.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can try below query using [**`$elemMatch`**](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/elemMatch/)

```
db.getCollection("works").findOneAndUpdate(
  {
    "MyOwnID": "123456789",
    "MyArray": { "$elemMatch": { "Field1": "FooName1", "Field2": "FooSpec2" }}
  },
  { "$set": { "MyArray.$.FieldToUpdate": 4321 }} 
)
```

Comment: This solution works. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

You tried with [arrayFilters](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/positional-filtered/), but probably in a wrong way, becuse it's working with it. It's not very clear in mongoDB doc, but $[myRef] acts as a placeholder for arrayFilters. Knowing that, you can do this to achieve your goal :

```
db['01'].findOneAndUpdate(
  {MyOwnID: '123456789'},
  {$set:{"MyArray.$[object].FieldToUpdate":1234}},
  {arrayFilters:[{ $and:[{'object.Field1': 'FooName1' },{ 'object.Field2': 'FooSpec1' }]}]}
)
```

Note that the unique document in arrayFilters is needed (with $and operator), because both conditions refer to the placeholder. If you put 2 conditions,

> ({arrayFilters:[{'object.Field1': 'FooName1' },{ 'object.Field2':
>   'FooSpec1' }]})

MongoDB will complain about two criteria with same base placeholder.

While the answer given by @Anthony Winzlet is right and works perfectly, it will only update the first array element matching conditions defined in $elemMatch, that's why i avoid to use it like that (unless having a unique index on including MyArray.Field1 and MyArray.Field2, you can't be sure that the matching element is unique in your array)

Comment: I tried, but it give an error: No array filter found for identifier 'object' in path "MyArray.$[object].FieldToUpdate"

Comment: Suprising, i tried it before posting. Which version do you use?

Comment: The version is v3.4.6

Comment: ok, this oprator start with 3.6. Use other answer, or consider ugrading your version (4+ today)

Comment: ok. Thanks. I'll keep it in mind!